# Meaning of degenerate complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Let $f : N \to C^3 \times C^3$ be a  holomorhic map where $N$ is an open subset of $C^2$ and $\phi : U \to N$ such that $q= \phi(z)$ be a solution to the equation $\langle{f(q),z}\rangle = 1 $ where  $U$ is an open subset of $C^3$.

Let $q \in N$ be arbitrarily fixed and write $f(q) = u(q) +j v(q)$ for $u(q),v(q) \in C^3$ then above equation can be written as $\langle{u(q),z}\rangle = 1 $ and $\langle{v(q),z}\rangle = 0 $ where $\langle{.,.}\rangle$ denotes a bilinear form on $C^3$.

In case we have 
$$\langle{u(q),u(q)}\rangle = 0, \qquad \langle{v(q),v(q)}\rangle = 0, \qquad \langle{u(q),v(q)}\rangle = 0$$ with $ u(q) \neq 0$ but $v(q) =0$ then the plane $\langle{u(q),z}\rangle = 1 $ is termed as *degenerate plane*. But why it is termed as degenerate?

In case we have 
$$\langle{u(q),u(q)}\rangle \neq 0, \qquad \langle{v(q),v(q)}\rangle \neq 0, \qquad \langle{u(q),v(q)}\rangle = 0$$
 with $ u(q) \neq 0$ and  $v(q)\neq 0$ then the equations  $\langle{u(q),z}\rangle = 1 $ and $\langle{v(q),z}\rangle = 0 $ together termed as *non-null* complex line.

I am not getting in what sense terms non-null and degenerate are used?
Thanks!

Comment: The name "degenerate complex plane" is not (to my knowledge) widely used, much less standard. Could you please say a bit about the context in which you encountered the term? Particularly, in what area of mathematics or field of application did the term arise, and is there any extra structure on $\mathbf{C}^3$ in your setting?

Comment: i came across with this term in context of bilinear forms denoted by $\langle{. , .}\rangle$ on $C^3$: if $\phi : U \rightarrow C^2$ is a mapping on an open subset $U$ of $C^3$  and for $u,v,z \in C^3$,we have   $\langle{u,z}\rangle = 1$ and $\langle{v,z}\rangle = 0$ and we have $u \neq 0$, $v = 0$ , $\langle{u,u}\rangle =0$,$\langle{v,v}\rangle=0$ and $\langle{u,v}\rangle=0$ then it was written  that $\langle{u,z}\rangle =1$ is the degenerate complex plane.i am not getting why is it called degenerate?

Comment: I came across with it in context of bilinear forms denoted by $\langle{.,.}\rangle$ on $C^3$:let $\phi:U \to N$ be a mapping from an  open subset of $C^3$ to an open subset of $C^2$ and $f$ is a map from $N$ to $C^3 \times C^3$.Let $q \in N$ be arbitrarily fixed and $f(q) = (u,v)$s.t $u,v$ satisfies $\langle{u,z}\rangle =1$ & $\langle{v,z}\rangle=0 $ forall $z\in \phi^{-1}(q)$ & we have $\langle{u,u}\rangle$ =o$, $\langle{v,v}\rangle =0 $,$\langle{u,v}\rangle=0 $ then it is written that in case $u \neq 0$,$v = 0$ then we get the degenerate complex plane $\langle{u,z}\rangle=1$.why degenerate?

Comment: Still can't make sense of the question, I'm afraid. Since extensive additions appear to be needed, it would be best to make them in your question itself (click the "edit" button below your post) rather than as comments.